# Have comparable Object using underlying collection

Tags: java

The goal here is to insert elements into a `TreeSet` where the ordering is done by a custom objects internal `List`.

```
public class CustomObject implements Comparable<CustomObject> {
    List<Integer> innerObjectList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public boolean compareTo(CustomObject o) {
        #compare natural ordering of elements in array. 
    }
}
```

This is what I'm currently doing, it works but I was hoping to find a native way to do it.

```
@Override
public int compareTo(@NotNull AisleMap o) {
    if (o.aisles.size() > aisles.size())
        return 1;
    if (o.aisles.size() < aisles.size())
        return -1;
    for (int i = 0; i<aisles.size(); i++) {
        int compare = o.aisles.get(i).compareTo(aisles.get(i));
        if( compare != 0) {
            return compare;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to do something like `o.innerObjectList.compare(toInnerObjectList);` However I'm not entirely sure how to do this so that the `TreeSet` orders the objects by the array properly. Is there an easy way to compare the "natural" order of elements in an array to each other? Only way I thought of was to check for size then if equal check contents until one index of one array is larger than the same index of another.

ex: the ordering would be like so `{1,2,5} -> {1,2,4} -> {1,2,3}`

Comment: How about Guava's [`Ordering.lexicographical()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#lexicographical--)?

Comment: in general? you can indeed implement a comparator which takes a comparator of elements, and then knows how to compare a collection of them.